# django facebook app testing on localhost using django-sslserver with selfsigned certification gets rejected

Tags: python, django, facebook, ssl, https

I wrote a django application for facebook,and i want to test it locally.

What i know so far : facebook uses only https requests,so in order to do requests with my app,I installed django-sslserver and used self-signed certificate to run it.
I have an index.html page as a django view,just to test it is contained in facebook's canvas.
But facebook keeps rejecting my POST requests. Is there any way that facebook will accept that kind of certificate?

-I use [this](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver) as development ssl server for django

Please tell me to rephrase my question if it is not clear like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,after some digging i found out it is not the certificate's fault that my app gets rejected.It was the django's middleware class CSRF, in settings.py file.
It is used for Cross Site Request Forgery protection found in django's documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/)

I think i need to pay attention to details next time.